# Jersey I can't authorize the user when uploading files

Tags: java, file-upload, jersey, multipartform-data, security-context

In default functions I can use `ContainerRequestContext requestCtx` to get the securitycontext and username from the request.

But for some reason when using this in a function that consumes `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` I'm getting this error:

`org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.`

Code:

```
@POST
@Path("{albumcode}")
@RolesAllowed("user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadPicture(@PathParam("code") String code,
FormDataMultiPart multipart, 
ContainerRequestContext requestCtx) {
```

Without `ContainerRequestContext requestCtx` the code from above works just fine.

Whats the best way to get the data from my `ContainerRequestContext` and also being able to upload files at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution while reading through random posts. I found out that adding the `@Context` annotation infront of my `ContainerRequestContext requestCtx` solved the problem.

I hope I can help someone else with this problem couldn't find any other answers close to this.

```
@POST
@Path("{albumcode}")
@RolesAllowed("user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadPicture(@PathParam("code") String code,
FormDataMultiPart multipart, 
@Context ContainerRequestContext requestCtx) {
```